# android - facebook's take on handling share intents - how to deal with it

Tags: android, facebook

Just stumbled over

Discussion on facebook: [Android Intent Sharing is Broken](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423)

and learned that facebook's position on handling share intents is ..

> ... Our FB app handles the intent because it is an effective way for users to share content such as links (e.g. your app URL) on their Facebook. However, like I mentioned earlier, it is against our policy to pre-fill the message for our users because it erodes the authenticity of the user voice so our app does not accept the EXTRA_* fields . ...

I am now wondering how to deal with that. Surely I can understand facebooks position to some extend and anyway we have to accept it I guess. Nevertheless this facebook handling of share intents definitely leads to a bad user experience on the side of the android apps. Now

- is there a way to exclude the facebook app from handling the intent
- is there a way around to fill the field anyway

What I do in my [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dorjeduck.justdharmaquotes) so far is copying the suggested text to be shared into the clipboard and the user can paste it into the (facebook) field if wanted. This works of course yet nobody gets this I am afraid. So I was wondering what you do to deal with this unsatisfying situation of facebook's take on share intents.

Thanks buddies

martin

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "bypass" it is to integrate the Facebook SDK and create objects on the user's timeline.