# android - Share html link to facebook, twitter or email

Tags: android, share

I am trying to share an html link to either facebook, twitter or email. Here is what I have so far, but two things are going wrong.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

shareIntent.setType("text/html");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>" + htmlUrl + "</body></html>");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share!"));
```

WHERE `htmlUrl = "<a href=\"http://{url}/?q=" + queryString.substring(0, queryString.length() - 1) + "\" >Text to url! </a>"`

First this only shows the email application in the list.

Secondly it's showing up as full text within the email and not as an HTML item.

Thank,
Dman

Answer (score 2):

Your MIME type is wrong. Use this instead:

```
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

If you just want to share a link and not full-blown HTML, just use the url as the `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` value:

```
shareIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url );
```

Note that only a few apps (like GMail, Bluetooth and Dropbox) support sharing HTML. Use plain text to allow more apps to catch your `Intent`

Comment: yeah I realize I had that backwards but that still doesn't alleviate the issue

Comment: Try checking the content of what you put into the extras. The choosers apparently decide if they can handle the content based on the EXTRA_TEXT parameter

Comment: Not quite sure what I am looking for within the EXTRA_TEXT, I investigated shareIntent after putting the extra there and it is contained within the object as well as it is showing within the email when I select that from the list (but it is showing all the <!DOCTYPE html><body> etc. tags that I don't want in the email).

Comment: Try logging the content of the string like this and tell us what you get in LogCat: `Log.i( "LOG", shareIntent.getStringExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT ) );`

Comment: The output of this is the exact html that I am placing in the extra. `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href="{url}?q={queryString_Value}" >Text</a></body></html>`

Comment: The following works for me with mime type `text/plain`, but not with `text/html`: `shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=\"{url}?q={queryString_Value}\" >Check out my itinerary from the Ontario Highlands Application!</a></body></html>");`

Comment: This shows a link within the email vs showing all the HTML contained in the EXTRA_TEXT? hmm

Comment: Well I want to show user friendly text with the link, vs the link itself hence why I am using the `<a href`

Answer (score 1):

You only miss a small change to your code - use `Html.fromHtml` to encode the string as HTML.

a more detailed example is available at this link:
http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/05/17/sending-html-email-with-android-intent/

This will not allow you to share on Facebook since the Facebook app dows not support `ACTION_SEND` with `text/html` but this will allow you to share HTML content using the Gmail app

Answer (score 1):

Share to Facebook (using this method can only share the link)

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");
facebookIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
facebookIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareUrl);
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Share to Email (using this method can change the email content to html format, but don't work using default email client, it works on gmail client.)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareTitle);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(content of your email));
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to Email..."));
```

Share to Twitter

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, your content);
    intent.setType("application/twitter");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
shareIntent.setType("text/html");
```

should do for the html part. Why only the email shows up no idea, do you have other apps like facebook, twitter etc installed to handle share intents?

Comment: forgot to mention that I already tried with the type as you said and that still didnt work. Yes I have facebook installed on the test device.

Comment: have you tried just putting plain text - dont think that is it but your code exactly matches the official docu so time to look for strange reasons ...

Comment: Yes I have changed the type to text/plain and unfortunately no luck in the formatting aspect, although this does show Facebook in the list (along with bluetooth and messaging). This just leaves the issue with the HTML not formatting for the link I would like to send

Comment: facebook wont be able to handle html anyway but it detects links as far as it goes in my experience - but you cant pre-fill the textfield in facebook, they intentionally dont allow it - so you can just send a link from my experience and the user has to fill the textfield

Comment: i asked something in this regard a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695218/android-facebooks-take-on-handling-share-intents-how-to-deal-with-it the link in the post is the interesting bit

Comment: Thank you for the information. For the time being I would be happy enough getting the HTML link to work within the emailing system and then I can take on that task. Thanks for the help thus far.