# How to share text in facebook from my App

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share text in facebook from my App. I have searched and found the following code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content to share");
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
```

This gives me list of all applications that supports the `ACTION_SEND`, I want to share only in facebook. How can I get only facebook? Can any one help me?

Comment: Does your current code even work if you select the Facebook app? From what I remember, the current version of the Facebook app deliberately discards text sent to it with ACTION_SEND, leaving you with an empty sharing screen anyway (apparently [by design](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/183741161701648?browse=search_4f23e4a3ae82b8476430237).)

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_SEND doesnt work with facebook as Matt already commented. I posted a question about this a while ago

[facebook's take on handling share intents - how to deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695218/android-facebooks-take-on-handling-share-intents-how-to-deal-with-it)

So even if you manage to limit ACTION_SEND to only facebook - I doubt this is possible - it wouldnt help. So most likely using the facebook android sdk

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

is your way to go.